# Deducing the definition of subobject classifier from Sub functor being representable

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, yoneda-lemma, categorical-logic

As the title says.

Let's consider some category $C$ and the contravariant functor $Sub : C^{op} \rightarrow Set$ that for each object gives its set of subobjects.

The introductory book by Leinster says that by the Yoneda lemma, $Sub$ being representable amounts to there being an object $\Omega$ and an element $t:Sub(\Omega)$ which satisfy the definition of subobject classifier, and gives no more explanation.

How is he using the Yoneda lemma exactly here?

Comment: Does your definition of subobject classifier involve a morphism $\mathsf{true} : 1 \to \Omega$ where $1$ is a final object of $C$, or a monomorphism $\mathsf{true} : \Omega_0 \to \Omega$?  Because the Yoneda lemma corollary gives the latter directly; and then showing that the object $\Omega_0$ that you get is a final object takes a little work.

Comment: Also, to get the Sub functor, you need to assume $C$ is well-powered (i.e. the class of subobjects of every object is small / set-sized), and that $C$ has fibered products (at least in the case where one is a monomorphism) -- right?

Answer (score 1):

A functor $F : C^{\text{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ being representable means that there is an object $c$ of $C$ and a natural isomorphism $C(-, c) \to F$.  The Yoneda lemma gives a bijection $[C^{\text{op}}, \mathrm{Set}](C(-, c), F) \cong Fc$.  Therefore a natural transformation $C(-, c) \to F$ (which is an element of the left hand side of this bijection) is the same thing as an element of $Fc$ (which is the right hand side of this bijection).  So a functor $F : C^{\text{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is representable just in case there is an object $c$ of $C$ and an element $x$ of $Fc$ such that the element of $[C^{\text{op}}, \mathrm{Set}](C(-, c), F)$ corresponding to $x$ under the Yoneda lemma is a natural isomorphism.

Comment: It might also be useful to use the precise definition of the Yoneda isomorphism to get a precise statement of when the last condition happens: it's exactly when for every object $d$ of $C$ and every element $y \in F(d)$ there exists a unique morphism $f \in C(d, c)$ such that $y = F(f)(x)$.

Comment: (OK, and I guess that also uses the fact: a natural transformation $\alpha$ is an isomorphism in the functor category if and only if $\alpha(c)$ is an isomorphism for each object $c$.)